# How to two buttons to one div in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created one button on my div element and I would like to create another.

I have already tried 
var textForButton2 = document.createTextNode("Try again!");
  button.appendChild(textForButton2);
under the first buttons code but that simply made a bigger button with both texts inside

```
// Adding a button
var button = document.createElement("Button");
var textForButton = document.createTextNode("Next->");
button.appendChild(textForButton);
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  alert("Hi!");
});
divElement.appendChild(button);

// Appending the div element to body
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(divElement);
```

I would like two buttons in my div(which I won't show the code for concise purposes) instead of just the one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another button element.

```
var secondButton = document.createElement("button");
var textForButton2 = document.createTextNode("Try again!"); 
secondButton.appendChild(textForButton2);
```

Comment: I don't know why I didn' think of that. Worked perfectly, thanks!